# Meaning of sacoches in Quebecois French?

Tags: traduction

I translate it as *saddlebags*, but it doesn't seem to fit the context. I'm thinking there's a Quebecois usage, meaning simply *bags* or maybe *purse*?

**Updated from comment:**

It is from an ad that shows a crossbody phone "case" (softbody, not hard) with a strap; it allows you to free your hands when you don't want to/can't carry your phone. Sacoche is with an "s," and Google translates that as "saddlebags" (obviously not correct). Keep in mind the "case" is only the size of a cell phone. So, would you call it a "bag"?

Comment: Well, it would really help if you could give some context then, if you feel there's something wrong with this word in that context... That said, in Belgium French "sacoche" can indeed also mean "purse". I don't know for Quebec.

Comment: I apologize for not giving context; I honestly thought the translation was going to be straightforward. It is from an ad that shows a crossbody phone "case" (softbody, not hard) with a strap; it allows you to free your hands when you don't want to/can't carry your phone. Sacoche is with an "s," and Google translates that as "saddlebags" (obviously not correct). Keep in mind the "case" is only the size of a cell phone. So, would you call it a "bag"?

Comment: I might be calling that a bag, but I'm not exactly the best source for English, neither is this SE site... It could be called a Hooloo Voodoo Phone Purse in the USA without me knowing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about finding an English word

Comment: Can you please guide me to the correct place? I see other questions in this group about translating French to English.

Comment: n.b. - I'm trying to find the correct translation of this word, so that the meaning in English matches the French.

Answer (score 3):

Sacoche in French Quebecois mean principaly the **hand bag** of a **women**.

It can also mean a object like a **sac banane**, but it got a strong connotation of a feminine's article. Hearing someone to tell that to a man's bag could make me think if he wanted to make a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Notice: Answer from a Belgian French perspective

This is a tricky one. If I were to see the picture you describe and the product was labelled as "sacoche" I would probably not find it too much off.
But if I had to choose only 1 word to describe it, I probably wouldn't use "sacoche" but pochette, housse, étui, sac,...

Using more words you can also be more or less descriptive, and then refer to "sacoche":

> Sacoche/Sac/Housse/Étui/Pochette bandoulière pour téléphone portable

"Bandoulière" designate the shoulder strap. "Porter quelquechose en bandoulière" means carrying it using the shoulder strap, usually across the body.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share a picture, as it's from a site that is not yet live. FYI: the Quebecois word is "sacoches" (plural), which translates to "saddlebags," which this item definitely is not and, since this website will be selling these items, using the word "bag" just doesn't seem attractive enough, if you know what I mean, and "pouch" also describes what it is, but is not attractive enough for sales. At any rate, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a derogation in Quebec
If used against a woman it basically means an well-used old bag, saggy, wrinkly and definitely NOT sanitary, as in an old prostitute who was forced to retire.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).